# PowerBI search for text in column

Tags: search, text, powerbi

I am looking for particular text in a column in data, if the text exists, I want to return True if not false.
This is the code I have:
Test = if(containsstring(DS[Name]=".SA"),"T","F")
I have tried it with wildcards and no wild cards.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to write a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: Calculated Column

Comment: Are you looking for True/False for each row or for the column as a whole?

Comment: Yes, true/false for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `=` with a comma `,`.

```
Test = IF ( CONTAINSSTRING ( DS[Name], ".SA" ), "T", "F" )
```